# Django Rest Framework logout not working after token authentication

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt

I had succeeded in making authentication with token authentication mechanism in django rest framework but when i call logout function it showing error **'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'auth_token'**, don't know why it returning AnonymousUser.

```
## Serializer ##
class AdminLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get("username", "")
        password = data.get("password", "")

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    data["user"] = user
                else:
                    msg = 'User is deactivated'
                    raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
            else:
                msg = "Unable to login with given credentials"
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = 'Must Provide Username and password'
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        return data

## Viewsets ##

class AdminLoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = AdminLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        # django_login(request, user)
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({"token": token.key, 'id': token.user.id}, status=200)


class AdminLogoutView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]

    def post(self, request):
        # django_logout(request)
        **request.user.auth_token.delete()**
        return Response(status=204)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not providing the token you have got from the `loginView` in the new request to `logoutView`. so the TokenAuthentication fills the `request.user` with AnonymousUser.

add the `IsAuthenticated` permission class to your LogoutViet to prevent the unauthenticated users.

```
from rest_framework import permissions
class AdminLogoutView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

also, check the TokenAuthentication routine, and put the token in the requests exactly like that. you should pass the token in `Authorization` HTTP header in a pattern like this for example:

```
Authorization: Token 401f7ac837da42b97f613d789819ff93537bee6a
```

Comment: Thank you changak i will pass toekn in authorization also how can i contact you if i need something help

Comment: I suggest you ask your questions here, you got more chance to find your best answer.  but anyway, you can find my contact information in my profile.